# Array single cell to entire column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I've got something I think is really simple to achieve but I just can't figure out (total amateur here).

I have referenced a single cell from another sheet in the very top of my working sheet and would like for the entire column to populate with the same value. I've tried a few different formulas and can't seem to crack it. Would INDIRECT perhaps be a better route?

[Attempt 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EckW.png) `=ArrayFormula(Copy!$D$5)`

[Attempt 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WB15j.png) `=ArrayFormula({Copy!D5})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(A:A),Copy!D5))`

This assumes that you want the results to start in Row 1 of your column and that the above formula is in the top cell of your result column. If you want the results to start in Row 2 (e.g.), then place the formula in Row 2 of your result column and use this:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(A2:A),Copy!D5))`

... etc.

Comment: Happy I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, put this in your cell J2:

`={Copy!D5:D}`

`{}` works as an array without the need to specify the `ARRAYFORMULA` function. It gets everything from cell D5 and below, from the 'Copy' sheet.