# How to add extra column to query result in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet with many tabs. I want to add the value in cell AH1 of each sheet tab to the result of the following formula:

```
=QUERY({ALZR11!H2:Y; HGLG11!H2:Y}; "SELECT * WHERE Col8 is not null";0)
```

The added column should look like the one in column "Ativo", assuming the values in cells HGLG11!AH$1 and ALZR11!AH$1 are the ones shown in the picture. I need to add something to the above formula to achieve this result, but I can't figure out what.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

`=QUERY({ALZR11!H2:Y,arrayformula(if(row(ALZR11!H2:H),ALZR11!$AH$1));HGLG11!H2:Y,arrayformula(if(row(HGLG11!H2:H),HGLG11!$AH$1))} , 'SELECT * WHERE Col1 is not null and Col8 is not null',0)`

h/t @ErikTyler [Array single cell to entire column in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67460371/1330560)

The formula is essentially the same as the OP except that an extra column is added to the data range:

- `arrayformula(if(row(ALZR11!H2:H),ALZR11!$AH$1))`
- `arrayformula(if(row(HGLG11!H2:H),HGLG11!$AH$1))`

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: sample]

Comment: It worked thanks. I'd tried this formula before and got an error. The problem was that my google sheets were in Brazilian Portuguese and I didn't know that to make it work I had to use a backslash, like this: 

`=QUERY({ALZR11!H2:Y\arrayformula(if(row(ALZR11!H2:H);ALZR11!$AH$1));HGLG11!H2:Y\arrayformula(if(row(HGLG11!H2:H);HGLG11!$AH$1))}; "SELECT * WHERE Col8 is not null";0)`